# Is there a JDK method for changing a double to the nearest larger int, even if it's already an integer value?

Tags: java, math

I want to be able to 'round' up any `double` value to the closest higher integer, even if the value itself is already an integer value.

`Math.ceil(2)` returns `2`, since `2` is already equal to an integer value. I need a function that would return `3` in this case.

I can easily code this myself but am curious whether this already exists in the JDK.

EDIT: In the likely case that I will just code this myself given how trivial I think this is, please tell me if the following code looks okay to you:

```
public static double convertToNearestLargerIntValue(double value){
    return Math.floor(value + 1.0);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for integer values above 2^53.

Comment: `Math.floor(value) + 1` is probably a better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so simple, there doesn't need to be a JDK method.

```
Math.floor(value) + 1
```